# How to put if else condition?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Pretty new to algolia.

Need a template for algolia hit template. See script for text/html for template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-image">
      <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="hit-content">
      <h3 class="hit-price">${{final_price}}</h3>
      <h2 class="hit-name">{{{_highlightResult.name.value}}}</h2>
      <p class="hit-description">{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

I have another parameters `{{retail_price}}`. So if final price is less than retail price, I will only show final price. Else, show both with retail_price strikeoff.

The problem is, how do I write a if else statement condition in a `<script type="text/html">`?

Comment: Is this moustache template engine they are using?

Comment: How is this question JS related?

Comment: You have some fundeamental missunderstandings of what is going on here. You need someone physically with you or real time chat to help explain the difference between html, javascript, templating langauges, and back end code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about algolia but If I was you I will do a wrapper that receive all the parameters, validate the conditions, setup the data that I will display and then call the template with the correct info, something like this:

```
function wrapper_template(image, final_price, _highlightResult){
  var show = final_price > 2000 ? true : false;
  var html = template(yourTemplate, { image: image, price: final_price, result: _highlightResult });
return html;
}
```

Hope It helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a Mustache template as it appears to be, what you need to do is create a javascript script and create a flag which the template then uses. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(price < msrp) {
    show_msrp = true;
  }
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-image">
      <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="hit-content">
      {{#show_msrp}}
        <s><h4 class="hit-msrp">${{retail_price}}</h4></s>
      {{/show_msrp}}
      <h3 class="hit-price">${{final_price}}</h3>
      <h2 class="hit-name">{{{_highlightResult.name.value}}}</h2>
      <p class="hit-description">{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```